# Tried Ubdating Kernel; Now, Desktop won't load on startup

Tags: kernel, multiple-monitors, monitor

I get a blank black screen and a message that says "could not apply the stored configuration for monitors required virtual size does not fit available size" and says it can't use 3840xy and it's maximum is 1920. Any suggestions? I can still load the terminal using Ctrl + alt + f1, but can't display my desktop in recovery mode.

Comment: You tried updating, how?

Comment: I used this guide: http://m.wikihow.com/Update-Ubuntu-Kernel

Comment: As you can see, there are no packages on that repository https://launchpad.net/~kernel-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: I see you are correct. Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If your /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias is less than 100 bytes, that is the problem: Kernel module installation was broken, so the hardware is detected incorrectly. Use an older kernel. If you fix the modules problem with a new kernel, tell me how ;)

Otherwise, if the file is big, please disregard this answer.